# How to initialize a vector of vector of strings using for loop in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, initialization, stdvector

I have problem with initializing the following vector:

```
int main()
{
    ...
    int size = classData.size();
    vector<vector<string>> arrayClass[size][3];     // <-- problem
    for(int i = 0 ; i < classData.size(); i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0 ; j < 3; j++)
        {
            arrayClass[i][j] = classData[j+i];
        }
    }
}
```

It says that `size` must be constant value. Any thoughts?

Comment: You have a 2D array of 2D vectors of strings, which are like a vector. 5 dimensions is not going to go well when trying to use it.

Answer (score 8):

```
vector<vector<string>> arrayClass[size][3];
```

was meant to be:

```
vector<vector<string>> arrayClass(size, vector<string>(3));
```

which takes advantage od `std::vector`'s constructor, which initializes the vector with appropriate size, filling it with empty strings.